# Battleship JavaScript won't display the 2d array

Tags: javascript, html, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to create a simple Battleship 10x10 game, with five ships. But I kind of stuck at the first part where my 2d array won't work, like it won't display anything when I try to run it. Is this because of my syntax or what? `gameArray` is to display where the ships will be located.

```js
var gameArray=[];
var empty = 0;
var hit = 1;
var miss = 2;
var numShips =5;
initGame(10);
dispgameArray();
shipLocator();
dispgameArray();
dispBoard(); 
document.getElementById("part2").innerHTML = "<img src='water.png' alt='1' height='100' width='100'>";

function initGame(n){
    alert("initGame");
    var rows=0;
    var cols=0;
    for (rows=0; rows<n; rows++){
        for(cols=0; cols<n; cols++){
            gameArray[rows][cols] = empty;
        }
    }
}

function isOdd(num) {
    if (num%2 === 0){
        return true;
    } 
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

function dispgameArray(){

    var rows=0;
    var cols=0;
    var html = "";
    alert(gameArray[rows].length);
    for (rows=0; rows < gameArray.length; rows++){
        for(cols=0; cols<gameArray[rows].length; cols++){
            if (gameArray[rows][cols] == empty) {
                if (isOdd(rows)){
                    html = html + "X"
                } 
                else
                {html = html + "X "}
            }
            if (gameArray[rows][cols] == ship){
                if (isOdd(rows)){
                    html = html + "&"
                } 
                else
                {html = html + "&  "}
            }
            if (gameArray[rows][cols] == miss){
                if (isOdd(rows)){
                    html = html + "M"
                } 
                else
                {html = html + "M  "}
            }
            if (gameArray[rows][cols] == hit){
                if (isOdd(rows)){
                    html = html + "*"
                } 
                else
                {html = html + "*  "}
            }
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("part3").innerHTML = html;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There were a few problems with your code:

1. When creating a 2D array in JavaScript you need to initialize it, for example by doing `gameArray[rows] = [];` in the rows loop.
2. You were lacking a `ship` variable. (I've set it to 3.)

If you want an easy way to debug problems like these, try opening the Developer Tools, using the keyboard shortcut `Control+Shift+I` in Firefox or Chrome to open them. There should be a Console tab that will show you errors.

You're still missing a shipLocator() method, but I can't predict what is supposed to go there so I'm just letting you know.

```js
var gameArray=[];
var empty = 0;
var hit = 1;
var miss = 2;
var ship = 3;
var numShips =5;
initGame(10);
dispgameArray();
shipLocator();
dispgameArray();
dispBoard(); 
document.getElementById("part2").innerHTML = "<img src='water.png' alt='1' height='100' width='100'>";

function initGame(n){
    alert("initGame");
    var rows=0;
    var cols=0;
    for (rows=0; rows<n; rows++){
        gameArray[rows] = [];
        for(cols=0; cols<n; cols++){
            gameArray[rows][cols] = empty;
        }
    }
}

function isOdd(num) {
    if (num%2 === 0){
        return true;
    } 
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

function dispgameArray(){

    var rows=0;
    var cols=0;
    var html = "";
    alert(gameArray[rows].length);
    for (rows=0; rows < gameArray.length; rows++){
        for(cols=0; cols<gameArray[rows].length; cols++){
            if (gameArray[rows][cols] == empty) {
                if (isOdd(rows)){
                    html = html + "X"
                } 
                else
                {html = html + "X "}
            }
            if (gameArray[rows][cols] == ship){
                if (isOdd(rows)){
                    html = html + "&"
                } 
                else
                {html = html + "&  "}
            }
            if (gameArray[rows][cols] == miss){
                if (isOdd(rows)){
                    html = html + "M"
                } 
                else
                {html = html + "M  "}
            }
            if (gameArray[rows][cols] == hit){
                if (isOdd(rows)){
                    html = html + "*"
                } 
                else
                {html = html + "*  "}
            }
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("part3").innerHTML = html;
}
```

```html
<div id="part3"></div>
```